# SQL GROUP BY where either column has same value

Tags: sql, average, aggregate-functions, unpivot

I have the following table

```
User A | User B | Value
-------+--------+------
   1   |    2   |  60
   3   |    1   |  10
   4   |    5   |  50
   3   |    5   |  50  
   5   |    1   |  80
   2   |    3   |  10
```

I want group together records where either user a = x or user b = x, in order to find averages.

e.g. User 1 appears in the table 3 times, once as 'User A' and twice as 'User B'. So I would want to carry out my `AVG()` function using those three rows.

I need the highest and lowest average values. Such a query would break down the above table into the following groups:

```
User | Avg Value
-----+-----
  1  | 50
  2  | 35
  3  | 23.33
  4  | 50
  5  | 60
```

and then return

```
Highest Avg | Lowest Avg
------------+-----------
     60     |   23.33
```

I know that `GROUP BY` collects together records where a column has the same value. I want to collect together records where either one of two columns has the same value. I have searched through many solutions but can't seem to find one that meets my problem.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A portable option uses `union all`:

```
select usr, avg(value) avg_value
from (
    select usera usr, value from mytable
    union all select userb, value from mytable
) t
group by usr
```

This gives you the first resultset. Then, you can add another level of aggregataion to get the maximum and minimum average:

```
select min(avg_value) min_avg_value, max(avg_value) max_avg_value
from (
    select usr, avg(value) avg_value
    from (
        select usera usr, value from mytable
        union all select userb, value from mytable
    ) t
    group by usr
) t
```

In databases that support lateral joins and `values()`, this is most convinently (and efficiently) expressed as follows:

```
select min(avg_value) min_avg_value, max(avg_value) max_avg_value
from (
    select usr, avg(value) avg_value
    from mytable t
    cross join lateral (values (usera, value), (userb, value)) as x(usr, value)
    group by usr
) t
```

This would work in Postgres for example. In SQL Server, you would just replace `cross join lateral` with `cross apply`.

Comment: Fantastic, I appreciate you breaking it down in order to show how to get the first resultset - this part will be useful for situations other than the one I asked a question about.

Comment: Should there be usr after userb?

Answer (score 1):

You can unpivot using `union all` and then aggregation:

```
select user, avg(value)
from ((select usera as user, value) union all
      (select userb as user, value)
     ) u
group by user;
```

You can get the extremes with another level of aggregation:

```
select min(avg_value), max(avg_value)
from (select user, avg(value) as avg_value
      from ((select usera as user, value) union all
            (select userb as user, value)
           ) u
      group by user
     ) ua
```